# It appears that the DeletionDate column in the Stack Exchange data dumps available on archive.org is always empty

Tags: support, stack-exchange, data-dump

I downloaded Post.xml file from https://archive.org/download/stackexchange Here, you can find what is inside the different XML files https://ia800107.us.archive.org/27/items/stackexchange/readme.txt It seems like all the DeletionDate column is empty for all questions. Where can I find the deleted questions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Posts table (and subsequently the Posts.xml) doesn't have deleted posts, so DeletionDate will always be null.

In the [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1728833) instance you'll find a table PostsWithDeleted and that table does have rows where the deletiondate is not null but only a [few fields are populated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157462/can-some-metadata-about-deleted-posts-be-included-in-data-se/266431#266431) for those rows.

The PostsWithDeleted table isn't exported to the datadump. So you can't find deleted questions in the datadump.

The answer over on MSE for [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678) has the exact schema for both SEDE and the data dump. For the datadump you'll be looking for the italic table names.

If you want to hammer SEDE a bit and use its export to CSV feature you can get a lot of data out of it at once with some trickery. I have an [answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234774) that explains how that would work.